# Using a DLL project in a Win32 Project from same solution

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution which contains a DLL project and a Win32 EXE project.

I want the EXE project to reference an "Init" function in the DLL.

In the EXE.cpp file I have

```
extern DWORD __declspec(dllexport) Init(int num);
```

and I reference it like so

```
Init(0);
```

in the EXE project properties, I have gone to the linker's "Additonal Dependencies" and added "mydll.lib", and in the General tab, I have added the directory to where "Additional Library Directories" will point to my DLL's generated mydll.lib file

I do not get any compiler complaints about being able to find the file mydll.lib, but I do get

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl Init(int)" (?Init@@YAKI@Z) references in function _wmain
```

What am I doing wrong to be able to link the DLL that's being built in the same project as my EXE? When I do a `dumpbin /exports mydll.lib` the only thing I notice is that my Init function lists as `_Init`

Comment: Give the *complete* linker error message.

Comment: Updated with the full error mesage

Comment: Your DLL was written in C but you are trying to use it from a C++ program.  The C++ compiler does not know that it is a C function, it assumes it is a C++ function.  Wrap the #include for the .h file with `extern "C" {}`.

Comment: Wow..thanks for the help! Make that an answer and I will accept. I totally forgot to strip the .cpp down to .c for the new project when I added it, and didn't realize that until you said something. This has to do with the way the compiler does name mangling for CPP, am i right?

Comment: Also, the `__declspec` in EXE.cpp should have `dllimport` not `dllexport` unless you want the executable to re-export the function from the DLL, which sounds unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

Your DLL was written in C but you are trying to use it from a C++ program. The C++ compiler does not know that it is a C function, it assumes it is a C++ function. Wrap the #include for the .h file with extern "C" {}. – Hans Passant Jul 24 at 22:54

Wow..thanks for the help! Make that an answer and I will accept. I totally forgot to strip the .cpp down to .c for the new project when I added it, and didn't realize that until you said something. This has to do with the way the compiler does name mangling for CPP, am i right? – Derek Jul 24 at 22:56